# When I run my python code i get this error Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want run my code and get this error.
my IDE is pycharm 2021.3.3 and i work on machine learning.i don't know why i get this error : Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409). I try run this code in python console but It dosen't run

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from pathlib import Path
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    shuffle=True
)

model_structure = model.to_json()
f = Path("model_structure.json")
f.write_text(model_structure)

model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

Comment: Comment out `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`. Is tensorflow using GPU or CPU? How much memory does your code use? Have you tried on another computer?

Comment: Please try again by importing keras from tensorflow - `from tensorflow import keras` , `from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10`, `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`, from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D`. Let us know if the issue still persists as I tried replicating the same code in Pycharm and it does not show any error. If you could also let us know the tensorflow version you are using along with python version?